# How to compare mtime of symbolic links in bash?

Tags: bash, symlink, filemtime

In bash, one can test whether `file1` is older than `file2`:

```
  if [[ file1 -ot file2 ]]; then
    ...
  fi
```

If `file1` or `file2` (or both) are symbolic links, I want files compared by mtime of symbolic link itself, not the file it points to (i.e. I want bash not to follow symbolic links).

Is it even possible without using an external program? In any case, what is the best way to do it.

Comment: You have to use an external program like `stat`.

Answer (score 0):

```
#Compares modification dates on files (or links for that matter)
fname1=f1.txt
fname2=f2.txt

file1=$(date +%s -d "$(stat $fname1 | grep Modify | awk '{print $2" "$3}')")
file2=$(date +%s -d "$(stat $fname2 | grep Modify | awk '{print $2" "$3}')")

if [ $file1 -gt $file2 ];then
    echo $fname1 is newer than $fname1
else
    echo $fname1 is older than $fname2
fi
```